# What happened to Kintoki Sakata?

Tags: gintama

In the beginning of the 3rd season of Gintama,

> Gintoki was suspiciously missing and was replaced by a blonde haired version of himself named *Kintoki*.

Later in the series it was explained why Kintoki was created and what had transpired after that which arrived to the point of the beginning of the 3rd season, but what happened to Kintoki after that? Does he just disappear or is there more information in the Gintama manga?

Comment: you know that Gintama is a comedy anime and does not have a stable plot right?

Comment: @shnisaka Sure, but up to that point he was the main character, and he simply disappeared, as in by the next episode it was as if he never existed. Stuff like that happens regularly in this show to side-characters, but for someone who took up most of the opening sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Anime Gintama has a lot of side stories. Kintoki Skata is one of those characters in those side stories. The reason why the main focus was on him was because he looks like Gintoki and he also carries the same name except that his name starts with K not G. There is no more information about him yet in the manga. However, there is a possibility that he might return in the future releases of the mange.

If you are interested in Kintoki, then you can read more about him in [this wiki](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Sakata_Kintoki)

Answer (score 1):

He returns in the Silver Soul Arc to help activate with Tama and other robots the 
"Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Gengai Cannon" to fire against the Altana Liberation army which was ocuppying the planet. Apparently he dies, though Hiraga Gengai says he's going to rebuild him along with Tama.

https://gintama.fandom.com/wiki/Sakata_Kintoki